# BoneCP with Hibernate 4.3.x

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, build, bonecp

I've updated hibernate to a new version in one of my projects, and now i have to update BoneCP too because the ConnectionProvider - Package Declaration changed in Hibernate 4.3.x.

The change is already on BoneCP's git but i can't find an updated .jar on their maven repo. So i tried to build it on my own with maven, but i always run in some errors.

Can someone hint me how to build boneCP successfully or where to find an updated version for the new hibernate?

Thanks!

JFYI when i try to build it myself with maven (mvn clean install) i get following error output:

```
[INFO] 16 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] BoneCP ............................................ SUCCESS [0.554s]
[INFO] BoneCP :: JDK567 compatibility .................... SUCCESS [1.336s]
[INFO] BoneCP :: Test Commons ............................ SUCCESS [0.422s]
[INFO] BoneCP :: Core Library ............................ FAILURE [2.326s]
[INFO] BoneCP :: Spring support .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] BoneCP :: Hibernate provider ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.520s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 19 16:01:18 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project bonecp: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionMaxAgeTester.java:[73,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionMaxAgeThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,int,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionMaxAgeThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionMaxAgeTester.java:[134,53] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionMaxAgeThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,int,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionMaxAgeThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[97,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,long,long,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[126,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,long,long,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[157,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,long,long,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[185,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,long,long,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[213,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,long,long,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[244,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,long,long,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[274,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,long,long,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[297,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,long,long,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[333,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,long,long,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[371,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,long,long,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[383,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,int,int,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[404,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,int,int,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[429,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,int,int,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] /Users/mike.penz/Downloads/bonecp-master/bonecp/src/test/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/TestConnectionThreadTester.java:[456,34] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : constructor ConnectionTesterThread(com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionPartition,java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService,com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP,int,int,boolean)
[ERROR] location: class com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionTesterThread
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :bonecp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i was not able to build the source, but i was at least able to find a new bonecp-hibernate-provider.jar for the new hibernate 4.3.X

You can find it linked here: http://jolbox.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=556

I still would appreciate it if someone can help me, why i'm unable to build the source.

Thanks

Comment: Hello.!! @mikepenz. i am crossing the same problem now. will u suggest what exactly u found the solution and with some more details..
Thanks

Comment: @KanhuBhol what's your problem. You can't compile or you can't get it running with Hibernate 4.3.x? In the meantime we started using https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP in our company. It is in active development and even the dev of boneCP has recommend it. Perhaps you also try this one?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Dear i found a link on BoneCP configure with hibernate :
https://code.google.com/p/bad-robot/source/browse/trunk/cvs/hibernate.cfg.xml?r=56

And i failed to configure bonecp with hibernate 4.3.4.Final

Comment: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]

Comment: @KanhuBhol like i've mentioned in my post you have to download boneCP from the provided link from their forum. Hibernate has changed their provider class in the 4.3.x update and this will break compatiblity with old boneCP versions